# jquery validate valid and error class to form

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using jquery validate plugin. I have this form:

```
<form id="form-test" class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div id="test" class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess4">Input with success</label>
        <input type="text" name="prova" id="prova" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess4">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
     </div>
 </form>
```

and this is my jquery validate file:

```
$('#form-test').validate({
    rules: {
        prova: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4,
            maxlength: 7
        }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

If input is valid I need to add to div (with id test) class has-success and if is not valid has-error. How can I do this? thank you

Comment: yes but i understand how to change class of input element..instead i need to change div class

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form-test').validate({
    errorClass: "has-error",
    validClass: "has-success",
    rules: {
        prova: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4,
            maxlength: 7
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmmm...that's straight from the docs. It will give your invalid element(s) a class of "has-error" and your valid elements a class of "has-success". If it's not working, there is something else that's causing it not to work. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Just create an `if` condition if it is `.valid()`:

```
isValid = $('#form-test').valid();
    if (isValid) {
        $('#test').addClass('has-success');
    } else {
        $('#test').addClass('has-error');
    }
```